# reduce one dimension within an ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have points coordinates stored in a 3-dimensional array:
(UPD. the array is actually `numpy`-derived `ndarray`, sorry for the confusion in the initial version)

```
a = [ [[11,12]], [[21,22]], [[31,32]], [[41,42]] ]
```

you see that each coordinate pair is stored as nested 2-d array like `[[11,12]]`, while I would like it to be `[11,12]`, i.e. my array should have this content:

```
b = [ [11,12], [21,22], [31,32], [41,42] ]
```

So, how to get from `a` to `b` form? For now my solution is to create a list and then convert it to an array with `numpy`:

```
b = numpy.array([p[0] for p in a])
```

This works but I assume there must be a simpler and cleaner way...

UPD. originally I tried to do a simple comprehension: `b = [p[0] for p in a]` - but then `b` turned out to be a list, not an array - I assume that's because the original `a` array is `ndarray` from `numpy`

Comment: Why do you use `numpy`? Do you need an array? If yes, what is the problem with your solution?

Comment: Megain, `numpy` works faster then simple python array.

Comment: @Mowshon But as you are able to see, He didn't start with a `numpy.array`. So IMO this question is very unclear and shouldn't be answered.

Comment: You can just avoid manual removal of the singleton dimension and do `b=numpy.array(a).squeeze()`. Removes all the dimensions with len=1

Comment: @anishtain4, thanks a lot, `squeeze()` is a great solution - not sure about performance, but at least for readability!

Comment: @MegaIng, you pointed right, in fact I did start with numpy array, should have indicated it in the question!

Comment: The performance is definitely better than list comprehension, I think finding the singleton dimensions is O(1), so probably the best you can get. I'll post it as an answer so you can select it.

Comment: @anishtain4 No, the performance is _worse_ than with `a[:,0,:]`. It is readable, but has a really bad performance.

Comment: A list comprehension creates a list, regardless of what it iterates on.  If `a` is an array `p0]` will be an array, resulting in a list of arrays.  And the `p[0]` could be written as `p[0,:]`, highlighting the fact that it is indexing a 2d array.  `a[:,0,:]` is the same, just indexing a 3d array.

Comment: @MegaIng:
`%timeit b = np.array(a)[:,0,:]` > 3.5 µs ± 14.2 ns per loop
`%timeit b = np.array(a).squeeze()` > 3.44 µs ± 13.6 ns per loop
Seems you're wrong. But in any case, the difference is in the order of microseconds, even for huge arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *do* want to use numpy:

```
b = np.array(a)[:, 0, :]
```

This will be faster than a comprehension.

---

Well... I certainly thought it would be

```
a = np.random.random((100_000, 1, 2)).tolist()

%timeit np.array([x[0] for x in a])
41.1 ms ± 304 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit np.array(a)[:, 0, :]
57.6 ms ± 1.27 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit x = np.array(a); x.shape = len(a), 2
58.2 ms ± 381 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

## edit

Oh if its a numpy array then definitely use this method. Or use `.squeeze()` if you're sure it's not empty.

Comment: That syntax is very non-obvious. If I saw this in real code, I'd need Google to understand it. Please don't do this to me...

Comment: @TimJohns Ok, then you don't use numpy every day like lots of us. So what?

Comment: Fair enough. _If_ that's a very common idiom with numpy then I take it back. But in general, if there is an option that is easier for someone else to read, I prefer that option.

Comment: @TimJohns That is an exceptionally common numpy idiom and it is [very powerful](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html). It allows vectorized better-than-c performance on numpy arrays and (in general) much faster than comprehensions / for loops.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution using list comprehension:

```
b = [x[0] for x in a]
```

Comment: By removing the unnecessary use of `numpy`, this answer is "a simpler and cleaner way" as the OP requested.

Comment: the problem was that `[x[0] for x in a]` was showing as a list, not an array - now I realized it's because my original array is actually `ndarray` from `numpy`. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use numpy later, then it's best to avoid the list comprehension. Also it's always good practice to automate things as much as possible, so instead of manually selecting the singleton dimension just let numpy take care of:
`b=numpy.array(a).squeeze()`
Unless there are other singleton dimensions that you need to keep.

Comment: I accepted FHTMitchell's answer because his edit with `squeeze()` appeared before you posted - but really appreciate your input, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In order to flatten a "nested 2-d array like" as you call them, you just need to get the first element. `arr[0]`

Apply this concept in several ways:

- list comprehension (most performing) : `flatter_a_compr = [e[0] for e in a]`
- iterating (second best performing):

  ```
  b =[]
  for e in a:
      b.append(e[0])
  ```
- lambda (un-Pythonic):   `flatter_a = list(map(lambda e : e[0], a))`
- numpy (worst performing) : `flatter_a_numpy = np.array(a)[:, 0, :]`

Comment: The iterating one is the second best one. The best is the list comprehension one. numpy is the worst one, and the lambda one is unpythonic.

Comment: Thanks, I will put this info in the answer. ... and done

Comment: @MegaIng Worst in what sense? The only unpythonic one is the `for` loop.

Comment: All these valid.  There's debate among Python developers as to the desirability of `map` and `lambda`.  Sometimes the append loop is clearer than the list comprehension.  Oh, and you forgot one: `list(map(operator.itemgetter(0),a))` :)